# Count the number of column having non zero values

Tags: sql

I have the following script,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalCount1', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalCount2', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalCount3', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalCount4', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'TotalCount5', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'TotalCount6' 
    FROM [Party]
```

Please refer the screenshot as the output of the above script.

What I want:
I want a column after the Total as the total number of the column having nonzero values.
Like in the picture the values should be 2 as TotalCount1 and Totalcount3 have non zero values.

[image]

Comment: Check how to do a "pivot" in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
       ...
       ... 
       CASE ( WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +  
       CASE ( WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       CASE ( WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       CASE ( WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       CASE ( WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       CASE ( WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
          as SumOfNonZeros

FROM [Party]
```

Or maybe simpler

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeId ='4'  THEN 1 END) AS 'TotalCount1', 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeId ='6'  THEN 1 END) AS 'TotalCount2', 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeId ='1'  THEN 1 END) AS 'TotalCount3', 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeId ='10' THEN 1 END) AS 'TotalCount4', 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeId ='5'  THEN 1 END) AS 'TotalCount5', 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeId ='8'  THEN 1 END) AS 'TotalCount6',
       COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN TypeId IN ('4', '6', '1', '10', '5', '8') 
                            THEN TypeId 
                       END ) as CountOfNonZeros
FROM [Party]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CASE` expression over the selecting result, you can do this:

```
SELECT (
    CASE WHEN TotalCount1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN TotalCount2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN TotalCount3 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN TotalCount4 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN TotalCount5 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN TotalCount6 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Result 
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalCount1', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalCount2', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalCount3', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalCount4', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'TotalCount5', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId ='8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'TotalCount6' 
FROM [Party]
) A
```

Comment: You need `ELSE 0` otherwise you will get NULL

Comment: Also you miss the WHEN